# Dynamics 365 Salesforce Bulk API

Tags: salesforce, batch-processing, microsoft-dynamics

Does the Dynamics 365 support a similar service like the [Salesforce Bulk API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_intro.htm), which can download millions of records in minutes. We are using Java so [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Pfe.Xrm.CoreV8/) won't work. Maybe using [batch operations in Dynamics](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2018/07/use-web-api-batch-request-in-dynamics-365-to-execute-long-fetchxml/) could solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Whats your exact requirement? Do you wan't to load your Dynamics Database into an BI tool? Maybe Data Export Service could help https://community.dynamics.com/365/b/dataexportserviceblog/archive/2018/07/11/how-to-configure-data-export-service-with-an-azure-sql-database-using-azure-resource-manager

Or do you Need to replicate a lot of data between Dynamics and another (ERP) System? Maybe Change Tracking is your friend. You will need to do one full synchronization and after ward you can retrieve only the changed data since the last Sync.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/enable-change-tracking-control-data-synchronization

> Maybe using batch operations in Dynamics could solve this?

Yes, you could use a Batch Request with multiple Retrieves. This is tricky, because you Need some sharding logic.